# Add data in v-tab-item to be active based on v-tab each month

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want add data in v-tab-item from api to active based on v-tab each month. 
For example, start_at is January to be show on the January tab, start_at is February to be show on the February tab, etc.

template

```
<v-tabs v-model="tab" show-arrows >
  <v-tab v-for="item in tabmonth" :key="item.name" > {{ item.name }} </v-tab>
</v-tabs>
<v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
   <v-tab-item v-for="item in tabmonth" :key="item.name">
   <v-row v-for="lesson in lessonCourse" :key="lesson.id">
      <h3 class="courseName">{{lesson.course.title}}</h3>
      <p v-if="lesson.live">{{dateFormat(lesson.live.start_at)}}</p>
      <p v-else>{{dateFormat(lesson.onsite.start_at)}}</p>
   </v-row>
   </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>

<script>
 data() {
  return {
  lessonCourse: [],
  tab: null,
  tabmonth: [
    {id:0, name:'January'},
    {id:1, name:'February'},
    {id:2, name:'March'},
    ...
  ],
 }
 }
 method: {
 async getData () {
  try {
    const request = await Axios.get('v1/courses/onsite-live')
    this.lessonCourse = request.lessons
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}}
```

example data in api
.json

```
"lessons": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Live1",
        "live": {
            "id": 1,
            "start_at": "2022-01-27 16:00:00",
            "end_at": "2022-01-27 16:20:00",
        },
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "OnSite1",
        "onsite": {
            "id": 1,
            "start_at": "2022-02-29 13:00:00",
            "end_at": "2022-02-29 16:00:00",
        }
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with computed property :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      lessonCourse: [
        {"id": 1, "title": "Live1", "live": { "id": 1, "start_at": "2022-01-27 16:00:00", "end_at": "2022-01-27 16:20:00"}},
        {"id": 2, "title": "OnSite1", "onsite": { "id": 1, "start_at": "2022-02-28 13:00:00", "end_at": "2022-02-28 16:00:00"}},
      ],
      tab: null,
      tabmonth: [
        {id:0, name:'January'},
        {id:1, name:'February'},
        {id:2, name:'March'},
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    withMonths() {
      if (this.tab !== null) {
        return this.lessonCourse.map(les => {
          if (les.live) {
            les.month = new Date(les.live.start_at).getMonth()
          } else if (les.onsite) {
            les.month = new Date(les.onsite.start_at).getMonth()
          }
          return {...les}
        }).filter(l => l.month === this.tab)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
  // async getData () {
    //try {
      //const request = await Axios.get('v1/courses/onsite-live')
      //this.lessonCourse = request.lessons
    //} catch (error) {
   //   console.log(error.message)
   // }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-tabs v-model="tab" show-arrows >
          <v-tab v-for="item in tabmonth" :key="item.name" >{{ item.name }}</v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
        <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
           <v-tab-item v-for="item in tabmonth" :key="item.name">
             <v-card mb2 v-for="lesson in withMonths" :key="lesson.id">
                <h3 class="courseName">{{lesson.title}}</h3>
                <p v-if="lesson.live">{{lesson.live.start_at}}</p>
                <p v-else>{{lesson.onsite.start_at}}</p>
             </v-card>
           </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```